# Return part of a function first then do the rest

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have this function:

```
  handleClickSuitClass(rankClass, suitClass) {
    // first part I'd like to run AND return no matter what
    const newState = update(this.state, { [rankClass]: { [suitClass]: { $set: !this.state[rankClass][suitClass] } } });
    this.setState(newState);

    // second part I'd like to run after first part returned
    const presetId = this.state.preset.current;
    if (presetId !== '') {
      updateSuitClass.call({ _id: presetId, rankClass, suitClass }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          Bert.alert(err.reason, 'danger');
          const revertState = update(this.state, { [rankClass]: { [suitClass]: { $set: !this.state[rankClass][suitClass] } } });
          this.setState(revertState);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I want the first two lines to run no matter what, which is to setState on a state that toggles check (tick) mark on the item that has been clicked.

Then (after first part returned) if true make a call to Meteor validated method to update item as checked on the database. If there's an error, revert back to original state by toggling state again.

Currently it works, but it's slow. How can I make it so that first two lines gets run first and sets state, then run the second part after in a single function?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to make this two separate functions? when in doubt, try to constrain a function to performing one distinct unit of work unless it's unavoidable.

Comment: How would I separate it into two functions on a click event with arguments/parameters that still needs to run one after another? The onClick looks like this: onClick={ props.onClick.bind(null, props.presetObj) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState()` takes a **callback** as its second parameter. From [React's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

So you can do:

```
this.setState(newState, function() {
   // Code to be executed after...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer because it was what I asked for in the thread and it also helped me to see what the actual problem for the "slowness" is. It was because the 'updateSuitClass.call' was blocking the next click event. I just need to figure out how to unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified as follows:

```
const suitState = this.state.rankClass.suitClass;
this.setState({ 'rankClass.suitClass' : !suitState });
```

Later, while revert

```
this.setState({ 'rankClass.suitClass' : suitState });
```